# Error while deploying SSAS after modifying dimension & attribute properties

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, cube

I have created a cube that worked fine when deploying. After a added another dimension and altered some attribute properties it didn´t want to deploy no more..

I have some warnings but at least the ones that starts with "Dimension"... are old ones and didn´t do anything with first deployment.

I have done some searching and some people say it´s proplem with Impersonation option in the data source but i have tried changes this:

I have tried to change from "Use the service account" to the other three but without success.

I am running DIBS in administration mode on win7.
I am using SQL Server 2008R2.

In config manager i have setting: "Local System" but have tried change that one to without success.

In Management Studio i have granted all server roles in Security-Logins and no success.

What could be the issue?

```
Warning 1   Dimension [Internet Sales] : Create hierarchies in non-parent child dimensions. 
Warning 2   Dimension [Date] : Create hierarchies in non-parent child dimensions.       
Warning 3   Dimension [Customer] : Create hierarchies in non-parent child dimensions.   
Warning 4   Dimension [Sales Territory] : Create hierarchies in non-parent child dimensions.        
Warning 5   Dimension [Promotion] : Create hierarchies in non-parent child dimensions.      
Warning 6   AttributeRelationship [Product].[Product Key].[English Description] : The name specified for the attribute relationship differs from the name of the related attribute.     
Warning 7   AttributeRelationship [Product].[Subcategory].[Product Category Key] : The name specified for the attribute relationship differs from the name of the related attribute.    
Warning 8   Dimension [Product] : Create hierarchies in non-parent child dimensions.    
Warning 9   Errors in the OLAP storage engine: A duplicate attribute key has been found when processing: Table: 'dbo_DimDate', Column: 'FiscalYear', Value: '2006'. The attribute is 'Fiscal Year'. 

Error   10  Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.        
Error   11  Server: The operation has been cancelled.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set your dimension key properly. I assume it would be something like FiscalYear + FiscalMonth:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had many attributes that a changed keyColumn in and different types. It never worked when i did all changes at once and then processed so i tried to make one change at a time and then process after each change, that worked..